# Custom Function in C is confusing

Tags: cs50

I'm very new to coding and I need some enlightenment or explanation in layman's term since my vocabulary in programming is pretty low.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float discount(float price, int percentage);
int main(void)
{
    float regular = get_float("Regular Price: ");
    int percent_off = get_int("Percent Off: ");
    float sale = discount(regular, percent_off);
    printf("Discounted Price is %.2f\n", sale);
}

float discount(float price, int percentage)
{
    return price * (100 - percentage) /100;
}
```

The code works and all but I'm still really confused how the custom function works which is the  `float discount(float price, int percentage);`
how did it get the information from `float regular` and
`int percent_off`? how did `price` get information from `float regular` automatically and like it automatically knows that `int percent_off` will be stored in `percentage`.

Im not sure if Im making any sense with my question but I hope some of you got what I'm trying to say hahaha, I tend to comprehend really slow T.T

Comment: By calling `discount(regular, percent_off)`, the arguments are matched to the parameters in the function, in their specific order. In other words, the function knows it because you told it.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and easy to understand answer, I appreciate it!